# addeventlistener not working properly only in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, events, mouse

I have a basic list representing thread on a forum in the form of :

```
<ul class="thread-list">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

what I want to do is when the mouse cursor is on the entire `<ul>` element, so on the contained `<li>` too, I add the "hover" class name to the `<ul>`, and a box-shadow appear behind the `<ul>`.

My css code is that :

```
.thread-list{-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;transition: box-shadow 0.5s;}
.thread-list.hover{-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;}
```

and the javascript adding the event is :

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('thread-list')[0];                                                   
ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e){
        hover = 1;
        this.classList.add('hover');
}, false);
ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
        hover = 0;
        this.classList.remove('hover');
}, false);
```

this is part of my initUI() function that is launched right after window.onload is fired.

The problem is that this is working great on Firefox 58.0.2 and Opera 50.0, but when I try on Chrome 64.0.3282.140, the box-shadow appears but not entirely, just on the left side, and 1/4 of the right side, and this is blinking when I move the mouse.

I also tried mouseover and mouseout events.

I suspect the fact that the event is also fired when I pass over a `<li>` element and not only the `<ul>` even if there is only the `<ul>` element that gets the 'hover' class added.

What am I doing wrong ?

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('thread-list')[0];
ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  hover = 1;
  this.classList.add('hover');
}, false);
ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
  hover = 0;
  this.classList.remove('hover');
}, false);
```

```css
.thread-list {
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.thread-list.hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="thread-list">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: It works fine in Chrome 66

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you're doing this ...

Use the `:hover` pseudo-class for that :

```css
.thread-list{-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;transition: box-shadow 0.5s;}
.thread-list:hover{-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;}
```

```html
<ul class="thread-list">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats's right, I tried to avoid the ':hover' because I read this was doing reflow, and I didn't thought that wasn't working like that anymore. So is this right, or can I use ':hover' without thinking to reflows ?

Comment: Well I learnt a new word, thank you ! And no, hover has no issue like that. It's just a CSS selector for applying custom styles to elements that are ... hovered.

Comment: @JosB actually it was no point even to try what you did because what you did is adding a class that changes the aspect, but this is of course causing reflow too (from your article "change the className of an element")

Comment: I just read somewhere when collecting informations on DOM that this was better to add a class than using ':hover', but if you're telling me its the same that's ok for me. The problem is still the same tho after trying it :/

Comment: How can you have a Javascript issue when there's no more Javascript ?

Comment: Well I only put the parts that seems broken, but i'm working on a javascript code. I got rid of the 'this.classList.add('hover');' and 'this.classList.remove('hover');' elements, and did the changes in the css, but I still have javascript, and I still need to assign my 'hover' variable to know when to refresh the page and when not thanks to it

Comment: They're probably not the same, and behaviour might change from one brower to another, but it's been a long time now since `:hover` has been added, my guess is what you read was a bit outdated, never heard recent complains about it

Comment: Then you should make another topic with your question and the code that is not working. Because I've been working with chrome for as long as I can remember, and I have never had any issue with listeners.